# Falcon php make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1

Tags: php, lamp, phalcon, digital-ocean

Using the DigitalOcean LAMP and trying to install Falconphp, but get the following error;

`libtool: compile:  gcc -I. -I/cphalcon/build/32bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/cphalcon/build/32bits/include -I/cphalcon/build/32bits/main -I/cphalcon/build/32bits -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -c /cphalcon/build/32bits/phalcon.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
In file included from /usr/include/php5/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27:0,
                 from /cphalcon/build/32bits/phalcon.c:204:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1`

Anyone know how to get this fixed? (php_pcre.h exitsts - but not pcre.h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you need to install `libpcre3-dev` which contains `libpcre3` header files.

Comment: Indeed that's what the problem was. Thank you!